# "$2" Not working in script

Tags: irc, mirc

my script that I had made is not working and was hoping you could all help me out, This is being used in my Twitch.tv IRC bot, i was hoping to rewrite the users whisper after "42" but $2 is not working for me! 
Example: "User1: 42 abc" I whisper another user "Me: you whispered, abc" 
Thanks guys! <3

```
on $*:PARSELINE:in:*WHISPER*42*:{
  PRIVMSG #channel /w User1 you whispered, $2.
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think there's an event called PARSELINE

Comment: @Denny Pretty sure it's new to mIRC, I saw it online when researching and all. I mean, what happens when i execute a whisper is it will just throw back, "you whispered" instead of saying what the whisper was.

Comment: @Denny, We're too old for this.. Apparently Khaled added new event called PARSELINE: http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/commands/parseline

Comment: lol @OrelEraki So do any of you know how to help me solve this?

Comment: Nope, I haven't used this before

Comment: @Denny Since you seem like a very active person here for IRC, do you think an answer will come along?

Comment: @skdfsfwse Not sure, maybe eventually.

Comment: @skdfsfwse The reason your code isn't working is because identifiers($ prefixed words) must be wrapped in whitespace on both sides to work.  If you want to concat other characters between them, use `$+`.

Comment: can you be very specific about of what you want? or can you give an entire line of the "whisper" event?

Answer (score 0):

after hours of trying to understand what you have posted try this:

```
on $*:PARSELINE:in:/NOTICE.+:42/i:{
tokenize 32 $parseline
PRIVMSG #channel /w User1 you whispered, $+($5-,.)
}
```

only use "$" when there is a regex match on "matchtext"
this PARSELINE event, will look for word "NOTICE" ignoring for case sensitive
 if in your network, notice events are known for "whisper" just change the word

in case this doesnt work, please replace your PARSELINE event with this one

```
on *:PARSELINE:*:*:echo $parsetype $parseline
```

and paste what you got